# How to use db.relationship in db.ForeignKey with Flask-SqlAlchemy

Tags: flask, foreign-keys, flask-sqlalchemy

Is db.relationship('Model_name') necessary to use with db.Foreignkey() in flask-sqlalchemy to specify a foreign key relationship without backref.